# "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item" in adding list of appendices

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

According to the following **non-working** example, I need to add a "List of Appendices" to my document:

```
\documentclass[doublespaced,12pt]{ut-thesis}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[toc,page,titletoc]{appendix}

\degree{A}
\department{B}
\gradyear{C}
\author{D}
\title{E}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\makeatletter
\@openrightfalse
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{preliminary}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
F
\end{abstract}


\begin{acknowledgements}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
    G
\end{acknowledgements}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection

\addtocontents{toc}{chapter}{List of Appendices}

\newpage  

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}

\tableofcontents

\end{preliminary}

\begin{appendices}
    \input{app}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

where `app.tex` is simply like:

```
\chapter{Procedures}

\leavevmode

The implemented procedures of ...
```

But I have no idea about the following thrown error:

> Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. ...entsline
>   {chapter}{Contents}{v}{section*.3}

The content of `ut-thesis.toc` looks like the following after faulty compilation:

```
\select@language {english}
\contentsline {chapter}{Abstract}{ii}{section*.1}
\contentsline {chapter}{Acknowledgements}{iii}{section*.2}
chapter
\contentsline {chapter}{Contents}{v}{section*.3}
\contentsline {chapter}{Appendices}{1}{section*.5}
\contentsline {chapter}{Appendix \numberline {A}Procedures}{2}{Appendix.a.A}
```

Comment: Your example is far too long.  Can you cut out all those packages and still reproduce the error?  Can you do it with `\documentclass{book}`, since we don't have `ut-thesis.cls`?

Comment: @Teepeemm: The `ut-thesis` package is available in the MiKTeX package manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\addtocontents{toc}{chapter}{List of Appendices}
```

is wrong. It should be

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Appendices}
```